# Concatenate a range of cells in OO Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have column A with these cells:

```
A1: Apple
A2: Banana
A3: Cherry
```

I want a formula that will string them together in one cell like this:

```
"Apple, Banana, Cherry"
```

Comment: I can not understand how concatenating a range isn't a thing yet.  That's fundamental to every programming language out there (array to string), yet spreadsheets make you jump through hoops.  Even if they couldn't handle multi-dimensional arrays they should handle a single dimension with no issue.  But instead you have to write macros or hand-code it all one cell at a time.  It's the dumbest thing about spreadsheet, hands down.

Answer (score 7):

I don’t know if it’s implanted on **OpenOffice** but on his cousin **LibreOffice Calc** since the version 5.2 you’ve got the function : **TEXTJOIN**

> **TEXTJOIN**( **delimiter**, **skip_empty**, **string1[, string2][, …]** )
>   
> **delimiter** is a text string and can be a range.
> **skip_empty** is a logical (TRUE or
>   FALSE, 1 or 0) argument. When TRUE, empty strings will be ignored.
>   **string1[, string2][, …]** are strings or references to cells or ranges
>   that contains text to join.
>   Ranges are traversed row by row (from top to bottom).

*Example : =**TEXTJOIN**(**","**,**1**,**A1:A10**)*

More info here :
https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_textjoin.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id581556228060864

Answer (score 2):

A different approach, suitable for a long list, would be to copy A1 to B1, prepend a `"` and in B2 enter:

```
 =B1&", "&A2&IF(A3="";"""";"")
```

then double-click the fill handle to cell B2 (the small square at its bottom right). The result should appear in ColumnB in the row of the last entry of your list.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.1.7 of Apache OpenOffice Calc, there still isn't a simple solution to this problem. CONCATENATE doesn't accept cell ranges, and there isn't a TEXTJOIN function like LibreOffice. However, there is a workaround.

*This is essentially a duplicate of [pnuts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505892/5313933), but with images to hopefully help. His answer explicitly addresses separating the items with delimiters, as well as the opening and closing quotations, as the question above uses. As the general question (how to concatenate a range of cells) is useful to many people, I think my answer should still be useful even though I haven't done that.*

In my case, I had one column with letters corresponding to finished worksets, and one column with letters corresponding to unfinished worksets. The letters only appear on every 8th row, so I can't view them all at the same time. I wanted to just mash all the finished letters together in one cell to be easy to view, and the same with the unfinished letters.

The example removes the 7 empty rows per letter and manually inputs which letters are finished/unfinished for convenience.

Column A is the "unfinished" column to be concatenated. Column C is used to perform the concatenation. Row 2 is the first row, and row 24 is the final row. G1 shows the concatenated result in an easy-to-see spot near the top of the document.

Columns B and D, and cell G2, utilize the same method to show the "finished" data. The formulas aren't shown here.

[image: Overview of the entire worksheet.]

In cell C2, point explicitly to A2:
=A2

If you may have blanks, as I do, there needs to be a conditional in C2 to treat the first cell as blank text, instead of as zero <sup>Note 1</sup>:
=IF (A2 <> "" ; A2 ; "")

[image: Formula for C2, showing its position relative to A2.]

Then, in cell C3, concatenate C2 and A3:
=C2 & A3

[image: Formula for C3, showing its position relative to C2 and A3.]

Copy C3, then highlight C4:C24 and paste the formula to autofill those cells.

[image: Cells C4 to C24 highlighted to show copy paste operation.]

Wherever you need the result of the concatenation, reference C24.

[image: Formula for the destination cell that references the result of concatenation.]

*Notes*

<sup>Note 1</sup> If N cells at the top of the A row are blank and you just let C2 = A2, the first N rows on C will show 0, and a single 0 will be prepended to the concatenation result. Here, columns B and D are used to illustrate the problem:

[image: Illustration of the glitch when the first row of B2 is blank and D2 doesn't use a conditional check.]

Answer (score 0):

Either use the [CONCATENATE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#CONCATENATE) function or ampersands (&):

```
=CONCATENATE("""", A1, ", ", A2, ", ", A3, """")
```

For something more powerful, write a Basic macro that uses [Join](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Basic/Join_Function_Runtime).

**EDIT**:

There is no function that can concatenate a range.  Instead, write a Basic macro or drag and drop `CONCATENATE` formulas to multiple cells.  See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5438.

Comment: Sorry I meant an arbitrary range like A1:A3. I worded the question badly.